# Integrating stripe gateway to google dialogflow not working

Tags: stripe-payments, actions-on-google

We are working with dialogflow transaction and we're trying to
integrate it with stripe payment gateway.

We use are using 'https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs'
repo as an example. And replaced the allowedPaymentMethods with stripe parameters.

[payment parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSMf8.png)

We are receiving 200 status code in the logs after "confirm transaction", but we are receiving "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later." in the device.

Comment: If the underlying error is coming from Stripe's API, I'd suggest contacting Stripe direct either [via IRC](http://irc.lc/freenode/stripe) or their [Support Team](https://support.stripe.com/email), as they would be able to look up the error. Be sure to include a request ID from your logs in the Stripe Dashboard (req_*****).

Comment: Hi @taintedzodiac I don't think it's a stripe issue.
I don't do anything yet related to calling a stripe api but only specifying stripe parameters to dialogflow transaction sdk and there's no error comes from stripe.

Comment: Can you share the stackdriver log of the error related to the request? If you use Firebase to deploy the Action, can you also share the Firebase log with me, so I can better assist you.

Comment: Hi @mandychannyc
We didn't receive any errors in the logs related to the "confirm transaction" intent.
Here is the log we received after confirming the transaction. 

https://justpaste.it/268s0